# How to determine whether I run a 32bit or 64bit Ubuntu install

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

How to determine whether I run a 32bit or 64bit Ubuntu install?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Did you try uname -m ?

It seems like the uname -m actually gives

- x86_64 when it is an kernel 64 bits
- i686 for 32 bits kernel

Otherwise, **not for the Linux kernel, but for the CPU**, you type:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

or:

```
grep flags /proc/cpuinfo
```

Under "flags" parameter, you will see various values. Among them, one is named "tm(transparent mode)" or "rm(real mode)" or "lm(long mode)"

- rm means: 16 bit processor
- tm means: 32 bit processor
- lm means: 64 bit processor

**Note: you can have a 64-bit CPU with a 32-bit kernel installed"**

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246007/how-to-determine-whether-a-given-linux-is-32-bit-or-64-bit).

Comment: How to figure out the bitness of the userspace?

Answer (score 15):

Usually when you want to find this out, you want to find out if the applications are running as 32-bit or 64-bit, not what architecture the kernel was compiled for. As sYnfo points out, you can have 64-bit cpu with 32-bit kernel. But more importantly you can have a 64-bit kernel running 32-bit userspace. In this case the command `uname -m` will (inaccurately) report 64-bits, because uname only reports kernel architecture.  In Ubuntu and other Debian derivatives, you can find out your bitness by running:

`dpkg --print-architecture`

For most cases, you'll want to use this command instead of uname.