# Is it 32 or 64 bit Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to determine whether I run a 32bit or 64bit Ubuntu install](https://superuser.com/questions/69668/how-to-determine-whether-i-run-a-32bit-or-64bit-ubuntu-install)

I typed `uname -a` in a terminal and I got the following output.

Is it 32 bit or 64 bit?

> Linux my-laptop 2.6.32-24-generic-pae
>
> `#`
> 43-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 16 15:30:27 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

32bit.

With a 64 bit platform you'd have seen `x86_64` instead of `i686`.

Comment: Thats true.  Mine outputs: Linux blaze 2.6.32-24-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 20 14:21:58 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux